# Не работает логаут при ограничении сессии

Tags: java, spring

Задача - вылогинить юзера если он зашел на сервис из другого ПК

Настроил SecurityConfiguration на ограничение сессий для одного пользователя

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
        .expiredUrl("/api/register")
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
    .and().and()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(....

  @Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
    return sessionRegistry;
}

// Register HttpSessionEventPublisher
@Bean
public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}

private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AccountResource {...

@PostMapping("/register")
@Timed
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserVM managedUserVM) {....
```

Запускаем проект (JHipster) - http://localhost:8889/#/, логинимся на разных браузерах под одной учеткой .

При переходе по проекту никаких проблем, что в одном что в другом аккаунте. (а должно было выкинуть).

Перезагружаем страницу - выкидывает на `localhost:8889/api/register#/`  вместо `localhost:8889/#/register` (если перезагрузить страницу к примеру на `http://localhost:8889/#/jhi-health` то перекинет на `http://localhost:8889/api/register#/jhi-health`)

Можно сказать что система отреагировала на дублирующую сессию.
Убираем "некоректный урл", перезагружаем страницу - `http://localhost:8889` и мы остаемся залогинеными в системе вместо того что бы разлогинится

Вопросы:

1. Как задать корректный url на рест?
2. Почему юзер остается залогиненым?
3. Что надо еще добавить что бы решить вопросы?

Comment: В документации есть ремарка по этому поводу:  
`When using SessionManagementConfigurer.maximumSessions(int), do not forget to configure HttpSessionEventPublisher for the application to ensure that expired sessions are cleaned up`  

 (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#sessionManagement--)

Comment: `// Register HttpSessionEventPublisher
@Bean
public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}` так вроде добавил

Comment: Да, это странно что не работает. Я не эксперт в Spring`е, может дело в том что у вас `public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher()` имеет модификатор `static`? Там еще в доках есть ремарка: `Alternatively, AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.enableHttpSessionEventPublisher() could return true.`

Comment: я пробовал убрать `static` и пробовал `@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}` - безрезультатно, юзер остается залогиненым

Comment: а если так: `@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}`

Comment: @Sergi безрезультатно, юзер остается залогиненым